# MySql Workbench memory

Tags: sql, xml, memory, mysql-workbench

I have a large sql table with 24.000 rows and I want to export all its fields to an XML file.
I am using MySQL Workbench but the select * query makes it run out of memory.
I could limit the results around 3-4 thousand rows and merge the files, but I wouldn't like to loose a single record while merging.

Is there a way to give more memory to MySQLWorkbench, or does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [mysqldbexport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysql-utils-man-mysqldbexport.html) which is part of MySQL Utilities that are part of MySQL Workbench. Please read de documentation in that link.